# add rule to convert ? and & by / htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

```
 ErrorDocument 404 /error404.php
 ErrorDocument 403 /error404.php
 Options -Indexes 
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST [NC]
 RewriteRule ^ - [L]

 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?domain.*$ [NC] 
 RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|jpeg)$ http://www.domain.com [L]

 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(profile)\.php\?eid=(78)[&\s] [NC]
 RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,L]
  RewriteRule ^(profile)/(\d+)$ /$1.php?eid=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+enterprise\.php\?url=([^\s&]+) [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,L,NE]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /enterprise.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

everything i right til now but one thing that i want from the site is that to direct the following link **http://www.domain.com/profile?eid=1** to this link **http://www.domain.com/eid/1**

please help this is something very imp

and also tell me if it is possible to replace all the ? and & and = by / in the url

Comment: Do you not want to show `/profile/1` as pretty URL for `http://www.domain.com/profile?eid=1` ?

Comment: no domain.com/eid/1 no profile

Comment: So is `/eid/` a fixed string and part after this e.g. `/1` a dynamic one?

Comment: eid is fixed but after eid it is dynamic the urls can be like profile?eid=1 or profile?eid=2, eid=3 or eid 88 etc..... but i want them all like eid/1, eid/2 or eid/88 etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have your rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?domain.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|jpeg)$ http://www.domain.com [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# redirect /profile?eid=1 to /eid/1
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+profile(?:\.php)?\?(eid)=(\d+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,L]

# internally rewrite /eid/1 to /profile.php?eid=1
RewriteRule ^(eid)/(\d+)$ profile.php?$1=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+enterprise\.php\?url=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ enterprise.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: wow awesome the page redirects now but the page goes on loading indefinetly when i check in chrome console i got this .. 
1:86 GET http://www.example.com/eid/js/error404.php net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
1:98 GET http://www.example.com/eid/js/error404.php net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
1:85 GET http://www.example.com/eid/js/error404.php net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: after providing the exact path the error goes like right now i am using src as avator/image.png but after doing this domain.com.avator/image.png the error goes   Does this helps you find the error ???

Comment: Sir what your htaccess file is causing is that it is changing all the links from domain.com/page to domain.com/eid/page please check sir...

Comment: No actually htaccess doesn't change links. You're using relative paths in your hrefs/js/css that's why it is appending `/eid/` in front of it. You can add this just below `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />` to fix it.

Comment: Soo sorry for unmarking... awesome work your code worked sir.. +1

Comment: @anubhava can you help me with this rewrite  please http://www.reurl.in/9259f1941

Comment: @sonamSharma: Please post a new question and I will attend it.

Comment: @anubhava http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35256498/replace-by-in-urls-and-make-them-more-friendly