# replace ? by / in urls and make them more friendly

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

hello all i have a url like

```
 http://www.domain.com/dash?do=about&w=me
```

but i would like to make it like

```
  http://www.domain.com/dash/about/me
```

i have these things in my htaccess file.

```
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteBase /
     Options All -Indexes
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
      ErrorDocument 403 /www.domain.com/error404.php
       RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?domain.*$ [NC] 

       RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
       RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

     RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

     # redirect /profile?eid=1 to /eid/1
   RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+profile(?:\.php)?\?(eid)=(\d+)\s [NC]
     RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,L]

     # internally rewrite /eid/1 to /profile.php?eid=1
     RewriteRule ^(eid)/(\d+)$ profile.php?$1=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

     # redirect /dept?did=1 to /did/1
     RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+dept(?:\.php)?\?(did)=(\d+)\s [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,L]

    # internally rewrite /did/1 to /dept.php?did=1
     RewriteRule ^(did)/(\d+)$ dept.php?$1=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

     # redirect /job-details?job=1 to /job/1
      RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+job-details(?:\.php)?\?(job)=(\d+)\s [NC]
     RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,L]

     # internally rewrite /job/1 to /job-details.php?job=1
     RewriteRule ^(job)/(\d+)$ job-details.php?$1=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

      RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+enterprise\.php\?url=([^\s&]+) [NC]
      RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

      RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
      RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,L,NE]

     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
     RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
     RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteRule ^(.+)$ enterprise.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

can any one suggest something to achieve this i have ?do=about&w=me comon everywhere and just need to do it like /about/me after the page.

Comment: Have you already changed the URL in your application to `/dash/about/me`? (Although since you say "common everywhere" I guess you haven't?) Is `/dash?do=about&w=me` the literal URL, or is `about` and `me` variable?

Comment: Are these URLs always start with `/dash`?

Comment: No the url can start with any thing and about and me is variable ..

Comment: Hello @anubhava sir, can you help me with this ??

Answer (score 1):

It is slowly becoming difficult to maintain due to so many rules but here it is:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /www.domain.com/error404.php
Options All -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?domain.*$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# redirect /profile?eid=1 to /eid/1
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+profile(?:\.php)?\?(eid)=(\d+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,L]

# internally rewrite /eid/1 to /profile.php?eid=1
RewriteRule ^(eid)/(\d+)$ profile.php?$1=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

# redirect /dept?did=1 to /did/1
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+dept(?:\.php)?\?(did)=(\d+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,L]

# internally rewrite /did/1 to /dept.php?did=1
RewriteRule ^(did)/(\d+)$ dept.php?$1=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

# redirect /job-details?job=1 to /job/1
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+job-details(?:\.php)?\?(job)=(\d+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,L]

# internally rewrite /job/1 to /job-details.php?job=1
RewriteRule ^(job)/(\d+)$ job-details.php?$1=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+enterprise\.php\?url=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,L,NE]

# /dash?do=about&w=me => /dash/about/me
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+([^?]+)(?:.php)?\?do=([^&\s]+)&w=([^&\s]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/%3? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ $1.php?do=$2&w=$3 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ enterprise.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Hi sir, I know the problem and thank you for helping me with this, the code wokrs but the some images are not showing up after updating this code .. can you find the error ??

Comment: After checking i found that the path of images are changed after i update the htaccess file..

Comment: Dear sir, i am getting remote server not found in opera mini browser due to my previous htaccess file .. Can you suggest me something ?

Comment: That seems to be an unrelated issue. This question is for a different problem of handling `/dash?do=about&w=me` URL. Are `/dash?do=about&w=me` and `/dash/about/me` working fine?